# Quelles sont les utilités respectives de la voix active et la voix passive ?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, passif

J'aimerais bien savoir quand on utilise une phrase à la voix passive.  J'ai fait des recherches pour comprendre l'utilité de chaque voix :

> La voix active présente le sujet comme agent de l'action .
>
> la voix passive présente le sujet comme agent subissant l'action.

mais vraiment, je n'ai pas bien compris.

J'aimerais bien avoir plus des éclaircissements sur ce sujet, aussi je voudrais savoir si tous les verbes se conjuguent dans la voix passive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De ma part, je comprends mieux lorsque je regarde *qui* accomplit l'action. Si c'est le sujet, je sais que c'est la voix active. Si le sujet *se fait* une action *par* quelqu'un (ou quelque chose) d'autre, c'est la voix passive.

Parfois on comprend mieux à l'aide d'examples:

**Voix active**:

> Le chat a mangé la souris

Dans cet exemple, le chat est le **sujet** puisque c'est lui qui agit, ou bien qui accomplit le verbe *manger*.

**Voix passive**:

> La souris a été mangée par le chat.

Ici, la souris est le sujet, pourtant elle *se fait manger* par le chat.

D'autres examples:

**Voix active**

> Mon ami va cuisiner un bon repas.
>
> J'ai fait mes devoirs hier.
>
> La voiture rouge a dépassé le taxi jaune.

**Voix passive**

> Un bon repas sera cuisiné par mon ami.
>
> Mes devoirs ont été faits hier (par moi).
>
> Le taxi jaune a été dépassé par la voiture rouge.

Answer (score 1):

La voix passive est une tournure **en général plus lourde** (pas toujours) que la voix active, elle doit être justifiée par ce que l'on veut exprimer.

La voix passive permet de **mettre l'accent sur l'objet de l'action, et l'action elle-même**, avant le sujet:

> La pomme a été mangée par mon frère = mon frère a mangé la pomme.

On pourrait **omettre** le sujet de l'action:

> Elle a été blessée (par une flèche, ...).

Elle permet de **multiplier les sujets, ou de les manipuler**:

> Il a été vu par Isabelle, mais pas par Julie = Isabelle l'a vu, mais
> Julie ne l'a pas vu.
>
> Il a été vu non pas par Isabelle, mais par Julie = Isabelle ne l'a pas vu, mais Julie l'a vu.

On peut **omettre** le verbe:

> Adorée par ses fans, elle donne des concerts gratuits = Comme ses fans
> l'adorent, elle donne ...

La voix passive ne fonctionne **qu'avec des verbes transitifs (avec des COD)**:

> *Je parle à Jacques.* **n'a pas** de voix passive.

Elle se construit simplement avec **l'auxiliaire être + passé composé**.

Answer (score 0):

The basic definition of the passive voice vs active voice is where the object of an active voice would become the subject of the passive voice.

Passive:

> Il avait été tué par moi.

Active:

> Je l'avais tué.

You can see that the subject had become the object in the sentence. The difference is a different word order with the same meaning.

***NOTE:*** Usually you use *par* something/someone; however, there are also contexts where *de* is needed.

> La reine est respectée du monde entier.