# What kind of conjugation is "être rapporté"?

Tags: conjugaison

My French textbook has the sentence "Le fait est rapporté dans les journaux." The verb "rapporté" looks like a past participle, but the preceding verb is "être" rather han "avoir". What is the name of this conjugation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the [passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice).

The subject and the object switch their role with it:

- *Les journaux rapportent le fait.* : The newspapers report the fact.
- *Le fait est rapporté par les journaux.* : The fact is reported by the newspapers.

See: [Quelles sont les utilités respectives de la voix active et la voix passive ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18283)

Comment: Merci, jilliagre.  My class has not yet learned that.